# Module not defined Nodemailer

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in react and im wondering why my SendMail.mjs module is not working below.

The terminal is saying that my sendEmail is not defined.

What does it mean?

sendMail.mjs

```
import nodeMailer from 'nodemailer';

export default sendEmail((req, res) => {
  let data = req.body
  let smtpTransport = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      pass: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  })
  let mailOptions = {
    from: data.mailFilled,
    to: `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`,
    subject: `Message from ${data.nameFilled}`,
    html: `
  <ul>
  <li>Name: ${data.nameFilled}</li>
  <li>Mail: ${data.mailFilled}</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Message</h3>
  <ul>
  <li>Message: ${data.messageFilled}</li>
  </ul>
  `
  };

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      res.send(error)
    } else {
      res.send('Success')
    }
  })
  smtpTransport.close();
})
```

I'm using axios on my client side

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
import sendEmail from './sendMail.mjs';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage');
})

app.post('/api/forma', sendEmail(req, res));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server starting at port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try replacing `import sendEmail from './sendMail.mjs';` by `const sendMail = require("./sendMail.mjs")` ?

Comment: I just did but now i have the following error  : require is not defined from require('express') File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement looks okay:

```
import sendEmail from './sendMail.mjs';
```

But have you defined type in package.json?

```
type: "module"
```

After declaring type as module, it should work fine.

---

If it didn't work as well, then you can try:

Oops, it used to export module.

```
npm install esm
```

Then, importing `mjs` file like:

```
require = require("esm")(module)
module.export = require("sendMail.js")
```

```
const sendMail = require("sendMail.mjs")
```

Note: This will only work if you have defined module as type in your package.json.

Comment: I did it too but still nothing.

Comment: I was thinking of my node version. Currently, i have a node 14.15.3V . I m going to update and see. Thanks again for you support

Comment: BTW, which worked for you? Is just defining module worked?

Comment: Well, to be honest, im still figuring out because the require method is not working. Im trying find solutions and already did many things but the problem is still persisting.

Comment: Keep me informed.

Comment: It works now. the only thing to do was using {} at the end of my require js file =>  module.exports = { sendEmail, contact }